# Convert C# regex Code to Java

Tags: c#, java, regex

I have found this Regex extractor code in C#. 
Can someone tell me how this works, and how do I write the equivalent in Java?

```
// extract songtitle from metadata header. 
// Trim was needed, because some stations don't trim the songtitle
fileName = 
    Regex.Match(metadataHeader, 
      "(StreamTitle=')(.*)(';StreamUrl)").Groups[2].Value.Trim();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be what you want.

```
// Create the Regex pattern
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(StreamTitle=')(.*)(';StreamUrl)");
// Create a matcher that matches the pattern against your input
Matcher m = p.matcher(metadataHeader);
// if we found a match
if (m.find()) {
    // the filename is the second group. (The `(.*)` part)
    filename = m.group(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It pulls "MyTitle" from a string such as "StreamTitle='MyTitle';StreamUrl".

The () operators define match groups, there are 3 in your regex. The second one contains the string of interest, and is gotten in the Groups[2].Value.

There's a few very good regex designers out there. The one I use is Rad Software's Regular Expression Designer (www.radsoftware.com.au). It is very useful for figuring out stuff like this (and it uses C# RegEx's).